# not work multiple jquery slide toggle on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

this jquery flip slider work properly in my wordpress page. 
i want to use this slider Ten time in the same page. what to do with that code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Id's must be unique, perhaps try using classes instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the id `$('#<element-id>')` selector, you may want to add a unique attribute to each panel's DOM node. It is possible to use `$('#<element-id>')`, but the code can easily become cluttered.

You can name this attribute whatever you like, so long as it is not an existing/reserved html attribute.

For example, lets name our attribute *"panel-id"*. Our markup would look something like this:

```
    <div panel-id="1">Panel 1</div>
    <div panel-id="2">Panel 2</div>

    <button toggle-panel-id="1">Flip Panel 1</button>
```

We would then want to use the [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select elements we want to target with the `panel-id` attribute.

For example, to toggle `<div>` with a panel-id of "1", we would use:

```
    $('[panel-id="1"]').slideToggle("slow");
```

To assign which button we want to toggle, we would want to assign a corresponding id to our buttons (like `toggle-panel-id` in the example below). This would look something like:

```
    $("button[toggle-panel-id]").click(function(){
        var panel_id = $(this).attr('toggle-panel-id'); // Get our corresponding panel id
        $('[panel-id="'+panel_id+'"]').slideToggle("slow");
    });
```

To see this in action, check out my [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kt5y49py/4/)

Comment: finally i got it, work fine... this code slide up and down,, is possible its work down and up.. means i want in normal condition its not show content what inside this  and after clicking on button its show content..

Comment: Glad to hear it. In that case you would want to use `$('[panel-id]').hide();` I have updated the [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kt5y49py/4/)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the element identifiers are all unique (`#flip1`,`#flip2`,`#flip3` and `#panel1`,`#panel2`,`#panel3`), your code should work just fine.